# Vuejs + vuetify + vue-router: body losing everything under <view-router> on refresh

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have a `vuejs` running with a simple config and I am using `vuetify` for the UI

```
   <template>
   <v-app fill-height >
    <v-navigation-drawer right temporary v-model="sideNav">
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-toolbar dark class="deep-orange accent-3">
    <v-toolbar-title >
        <router-link to="/">Example</router-link>
    </v-toolbar-title>

    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
     </v-toolbar>

    <main>
        <v-container >
        <router-view></router-view>
        </v-container>
    </main>

    <v-footer class="indigo">
        <span class="white--text">© 2017</span>
    </v-footer>
</v-app>
<template>
```

Let's assume that I have two paths : **'/'** and **'/profile'.** 
Everything is rendering fine when the user lands on the **'/'** page (which is the default landing page), however there are problems when the user is on the **'/profile'** page and then refreshes it.

What is happening is that anything under the `<view-router>` get's lost. So the result is that the **footer is not rendered.**, but anything above the `<vue-router>` is render correctly

If the user then navigates to the **'/'** page the footer is rendered, and will render if he then navigates back to **'/profile'**

What could be cause such behavior  ?

Comment: Are there any errors in browser's console?

Comment: No nothing - but the issue seems to have gone away after updating to vuetify 0.15